# "Validate" in XCode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to run the Validate feature in the Archive screen in XCode 4. I have an ITunes Connect setup for this app, though it has not been submitted yet. I've heard it is a good idea to run Validate, but when I try it claims `No suitable application records were found. Please make sure you have setup a record for this application on iTunes Connect."`

The record in iTunes Connect has the same Bundle ID as the "Bundle Identifier" in the Xcode `-info.plist file`. Anyone performed this validate function on their app before? Is there something else I need to do in iTunes Connect to get this to work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've tried many times without success.  Also I see non of the links listed in your accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to signal in iTunes Connect that you're ready to upload a new binary for one of your projects, exactly as if you were going to release. When you validate you'll say which project you're supplying a build of, which is used as part of the validation.

You can achieve that by clicking to 'Add Version', filling in the relevant meta data and selecting "Ready to Upload Binary".

Comment: thanks, i will try this out tomorrow and let you know if i have any troubles.